# how to put Search on Google map in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse

i am looking to put search on google map in android application can any one guide me how to achive this???

and want to display some text along with that perticular search location.

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: what do you mean with "put search on Google map"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after working three days on google map finally i have created a tutorial related to google search on android
http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=887